# HighCharts uncaught exception

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am trying to run the same code in this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2qfgg/11/) locally but I got error from firebug

```
uncaught exception: Highcharts error #13: www.highcharts.com/errors/13
```

The included script fiels:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://highcharts.com/js/testing.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>  // my js file
```

same thing happens for this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r6emu/448/) as well.

Anyone know why this happens?

**EDIT**: I've found the reason for the problem. Actually I have to put the `<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>` tag after my `<div id="container"></div>` tag, otherwise the uncaught exception will be showing even I put the `<script>` tag in `<head>`. I never put the script file in the `<body>` tag before, and this is the first time I met this problem. Can Someone explain me why that happen?

Thanks

Comment: Ran it in chrome, no errors popping up.

Comment: I did not put `$(document).ready` in js file, that's the reason. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This means that Highcharts is loaded and the config is loaded, but the renderTo option is wrong, or there is no div with that id in the page. See [www.highcharts.com/errors/13](https://www.highcharts.com/errors/13).

Comment: I've found the reason. But one thing I am still confusing, please see my updated question. Thanks!

Comment: Never mind. I did not put the `$(document).ready` in my js file and that's why it did not find the `div` tag. My BAD.....

Comment: Thanks for the answer but adding `$(document).ready` did not work for me. Still throws the same error. Can anyone please help

Comment: It's working for me.   highchart adaptor without using jquery was i tried. after that I chaged code to call library :// create a new chart
$(function(){
  $('#container').highcharts({
    chart : {
      type : 'bar'
    },
    // other options
  });
});============================// create a new chart
runOnLoad(function(){
  new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart : {
      renderTo : 'container'
      type     : 'bar'
    },
    // other options
  });
});     => renderTo: 'divID'    Has to mention.

Answer (score 2):

The element/div you are trying to render the chart to is missing

A standard set of logs that I would use to troubleshoot highcharts error #13 are

```
        console.log("JSON: " + JSON.stringify(chartingOptions));
        console.log("Render to element with ID : " + chartingOptions.chart.renderTo);
        console.log("Number of matching dom elements : " + $("#" + chartingOptions.chart.renderTo).length);
```

These should be added just before calling the Highcharts constructor

```
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart(chartingOptions);
```

If all is well you should see the correct element ID, and length as 1.

[Troubleshooting highcharts error # 13 | Highchart & Highstock @ jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/avz9x/)

Here is the log that is seen for the demo above

> JSON: {"chart":{"renderTo":"container"...}}
>   Render to element with ID : container
>   Number of matching dom elements : 1

Answer (score 2):

I think I know why you should add that tag after the div /div.
If you are using a JSP or any other server-side stuf. You should add your Highcharts script **after** the declaration of the div container so it can recognize your div's id and then proceed to render it. Just like I did in the example bellow:

```
    <head>
    <title>HighCharts :D</title>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container" style="width: 600px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myChart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Fruit Consumption'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Fruit eaten'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Jane',
            data: [1, 0, 4]
        }, {
            name: 'John',
            data: [5, 7, 3]
        }]
    });


</script>
</body>
```