# Highcharts error #13 while instantiating highchart on ajax call

Tags: jquery, highcharts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [HighCharts uncaught exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11486553/highcharts-uncaught-exception)

I'm trying to instantiate a highcharts objects with this code:

```
$(function () {
    var chart;
    var json = null;
    $.getJSON('{%  url ajax_search 'pie_chart'  %}?{{request.META.QUERY_STRING}}',
             function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
            {
                json = data.template;
                            console.log(json);
                chart = new Highcharts.Chart(json);
            });
})
```

The console logs the returned json appropriately.

When I copy and past in the json to where the (json) is, the chart renders. However, as it is now, it throws the following error:  Uncaught Highcharts error #13: www.highcharts.com/errors/13

Following that link it says:

> This error occurs if the chart.renderTo option is misconfugured so
>   that Highcharts is unable to find the HTML element to render the chart
>   in

However, again, if I copy and past the json (from the console) to where the variable would otherwise be, it works fine.

I'm sure this is something simple. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Check that element specified in chart.renderTo exist at the moment the code is executed.

Answer (score 3):

The element/div you are trying to render the chart to is missing,
can you share the `json` that is printed in the console? Additionaly, if you can add the following more logs to give us a better understanding of the picture.

A standard set of logs that I would use to troubleshoot highcharts error #13 are

```
        console.log("JSON: " + JSON.stringify(chartingOptions));
        console.log("Render to element with ID : " + chartingOptions.chart.renderTo);
        console.log("Number of matching dom elements : " + $("#" + chartingOptions.chart.renderTo).length);
```

These should be added just before calling the Highcharts constructor

```
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart(chartingOptions);
```

If all is well you should see the correct element ID, and length as 1.

[Troubleshooting highcharts error # 13 | Highchart & Highstock @ jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/avz9x/)

Here is the log that is seen for the demo above

> JSON: {"chart":{"renderTo":"container"...}}
>   Render to element with ID : container
>   Number of matching dom elements : 1